# Find rows by latest date and time of distinct few column values in a large data set

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have date in below format.

[image]

I want to find the whether the latest snacks eaten by serial number 123 and 101 were veg, non veg or vegan.

I tried :

```
SELECT      serial_number,Name,event_ts_gmt
FROM            TT T1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT      serial_number,max(event_ts_gmt) AS MAXDATE
    FROM        TT
    WHERE       Name = "Snacks"
    AND     serial_number
    IN 
    (

"123",
"101"

    )
    GROUP BY        serial_number
) T2

ON      T1.serial_number = T2.serial_number
```

but this gives me an error FAILED: SemanticException Column serial_number Found in more than One Tables/Subqueries.

Kindly advice.

Desired output:

[image]
**This is an example i made original data has over 40K rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()` to get the most recent values:

```
select tt.*
from (select tt.*,
             row_number() over (partition by serial_number order by event_ts_gmt) as seqnum
      from tt
      where serial_number in (123, 101) and name = 'Snacks'
     ) tt
where seqnum = 1;
```

This will return two rows, with the most recent data for each serial number.

Comment: This does not give me the latest rows of " Snacks " by serial number 123 and 101

Comment: Also, this does not give me the newest/latest result of each snack.

Comment: @VinamraBali . . .It just needs a filter on `name`.  Your question doesn't explain what the data is.  So, it is not clear that "snacks" refers to the rows where `name = 'snacks"` or if the whole table contains "snacks".

Comment: Thanks for your help. With a where clause and "desc" with group by i was able to get the result. Could you also tell me what eas wrong with my approach. Just curious :)

Comment: @VinamraBali . . . If one of the serial numbers has eaten snacks on the two most recent days, but the other has not, then you will only get those two snacks.

Comment: Even when i have grouped each serial number and applied seqnum = 1 to the code. Maybe i am not able to understand what you arr implying. Could you please explain a bit more.